# Ways to do a user imitate/impersonate in feathersjs

Tags: authentication, impersonation, feathersjs

I can think of two ways in doing feathers imitate.

First is to have a different token key per user role (feathers-client-jwt, feathers-admin-jwt). But this works if different role have different routes. like /admin and /user.

The second one is to have a second feathers client(for imitate purpose).
So if I will do an imitate I will authenticate using client for imitate.

Is there a another or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to implement a passportjs strategy for a password-less authentication i.e. only using the email address.

Then secure this proxy-login, accessible only to a logged-in admin user.